# paste into ngGrid from excel

Tags: excel, angularjs, ng-grid

Folks,

Does anyone know how to make the ng-grid work with excel i.e provide the ability to copy-paste from excel into the grid ?

I know of the

```
enableCellEdit: true
```

attribute but that don't make the grid work with excel.

Comment: Sounds like a biggie... for starters you might look at how to parse csv data in js : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data and the nggrid csv export plugin https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/plugins/ng-grid-csv-export.js

Answer (score 6):

HandsonTable http://handsontable.com/ is really awesome for this.

The author is working on an angular directive on github:

https://github.com/warpech/angular-ui-handsontable

They now claim on their homepage that they charge money. They used to have an open source version and originally it was all open source.

Comment: +1 for HandsonTable. very sleek and intuitive cell editing! works perfect with copy paste from spreadsheet

Comment: It is free/open source with MIT license.
They also have premium / PRO version with variety of support.
https://handsontable.com/pricing.html

Comment: it does not seem free for commercial use.

Comment: I updated the explanation. They have since changed licensing.