# Import excel data using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am currently working on a web-application using angularjs.I want to import data from excel sheet using angularjs and add it into the ng-grid.Please give me possible solutions.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of this^

Answer (score 1):

`ng-grid` is not yet ready for copy and paste from Excel.

There is an alternative grid mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19970713/4185234) answer.

[SheetJS](http://brianhann.com/easily-import-spreadsheets-into-ui-grid/) also maybe an alternative for you.

Another alternative is to get the Excel to save data in CSV format and use a library like [this](http://papaparse.com/) to load data in to `ng-grid`.